# How to move the Query Role?

Tags: search, migration, query-role

I want to modify the Query component from Server_A to Server_B on SharePoint 2010? and want to know how much time it will take to complete the activity? also what all are the process SharePoint 2010 will do in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What applies to the crawl component applies to the query component as well. I far as I know, every change to the search topology will make SharePoint rebuild the index.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the modify Topology.

Under Query Component, change the server from the drop down , select the other server name and nad create the drive location.

Additional you can follow thw link.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2010/04/16/search-2010-architecture-and-scale-part-2-query.aspx